# Serializing a tree object in c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, binary-tree, circular-reference

I got a simple tree structure which contains the following

```
public class MyTree {
 public MyTree Parent { get; set;}
 public List<MyTree> Children {get; set;}
[...]
}
```

Currently the class is much more complex, but this is the important part to my problem I think. That code is quite old and I cannot just change the complete structure, because it is used in many areas in a project I have to maintain.

My main problem is that I cannot serialize that object. (I start serializing from root object) I get the following message:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   MyTree

It seems quite clear why this happens because I have the children AND parent connected.

But how can I solve that problem? Can I disable serialization of the parent property for example?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I'd go for that as a dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark parent as not serialize item ([XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx), [SoapIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapattributes.soapignore%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [NonSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)). Check about different [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206993/182344).

In your case you add parent to xml, after this trying to add children. Each child has link to parent and serializer tries to serialize parent again and so on..